# Delete row from db if member no longer part of a group

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-delete

I have the following query to get all members and some information.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select m.`name`, m.`id`, m.`group_id`, p.`field_1`, g.`data1`, g.`data2`
                from members m 
                inner join pfields p on m.`id` = p.`id`
                inner join groups g on g.`g_id` = m.`group_id`
                where m.`group_id` = 1");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

I have the following code to insert new members into my memberlist.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //code update members
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO memberlist (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $row['id'], $row['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

However, I noticed that if a member is no longer part of the community, the name never gets deleted as I'm only adding new names.

Deleting happens with `DELETE` but what is the easiest way to check if that member is still part of a group in the original query from `members` and if not anymore, delete member with that `id` from `memberlist`? In the example below, I want to delete Arnold from memberlist because he is no longer in group_id 1 in members.

```
members                    memberlist
id | name   | group_id     id | name   | group_id
-----------------------    ----------------------
1  | Donald | 1            1  | Donald | 1 
13 | Jeff   | 1            13 | Jeff   | 1
25 | Arnold | 3            25 | Arnold | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do a query something like this every time one is deleted:

```
DELETE ml FROM memeberlist ml
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.id = ml.id
WHERE m.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but made me think until I figured it out. I added the group_id to my memberlist table and each member with wrong group_id I delete.